# Im trying to understand ember and ember cli conventions and file structure

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have set up a simple api and a new ember app using ember cli

However, while I can get a full list of 'items' to appear, I can't get a single item to work using params.

I have my files set up like the following:

```
/models
  item.js
/routes
  /items
    index.js
    show.js
/templates
  /items
    index.hbs
    show.hbs
  application.hbs
  index.hbs
  items.hbs
router.js
```

For reference, here is what I have in the files

I set up my **models/item.js** a follows:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I added my code to my **router.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('items', function() {
    this.route('show', { path: '/:item_id' });
  });
});

export default Router;
```

Then I created my **templates/index.hbs**

```
{{outlet}}
```

And finally, added my **templates/items/index.hbs**

```
<ul>
  {{#each model as |item|}}
      <li>
      {{#link-to 'items.show' item}}
        {{item.name}}
      {{/link-to}}
      </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

This works as intended.

However, when I click a link (/items/1), it no longer performs as expected.  It will show the items/show.hbs correctly assuming I do no use any handlebars variables ({{item.name}}).  For example, If I just include text, `this is my items/show.hbs` it will display the text.  When I add in, `{{name}}` it displays a blank page

Here is my **templates/items/show.hbs**

```
{{name}}
```

and my **routes/items/show.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.queryRecord('item', params.item_id);
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: model(params) ? should be model: function(params)

Comment: thanks! I originally had it that way. I changed it back, and still get nothing.

Comment: What does you console say, any errors ?

Comment: Also {{name}} should reffer to model {{model.name}}

Comment: `model(params)` is fine (as part of ES6 syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not using reference to model when using it in template

Here is my templates/items/show.hbs

```
{{name}} < This is a model's property- name 
Correct usage: {{model.name}}
```

and my routes/items/show.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.queryRecord('item', params.item_id);
  }
});
```

Way of using hash

```
            return Ember.RSVP.hash({
                something: store.find('y', { study: params.study_id }),
                somethingElse: store.find('x', 1),

            });
```

Comment: Thank you!! I had been trying {{item.name}} and {{name}} but never thought to use {{model.name}}.  That explains a lot.

Comment: It helps to seperate different data types better. Btw i reccommend using Ember.RSVP.hash. @RickyMason updated answer for hash usage. Then u need to refer to it using model.something.name